# Combinations of 1 2 3 4

Tags: c++, math, combinations, permutation

I'm writing a program in C++ where I need to take a set of items and generate all **unique** combinations **of all lengths**. I've seen a lot of examples on here that take a set like [1,2,3,4] and create [1,2,3,4], [1,2,4,3], [1,3,2,4], [1,3,4,2]...etc, but that's not what I need. I need to take a set like [1,2,3,4] and generate item sets like:

1,2

1,3

1,4

2,3

2,4

1,2,3

1,3,4

2,3,4

1,2,3,4

(and any others I might have missed)

What's the easiest algorithm to do this?

Comment: Knuth's volume 4A covers algorithms that do this.

Comment: @ElGavilan no worries, you were right on mark.. i was just trying to be ironic and funny about how even hw questions get so many answers, including from me.. can't resist a juicy little question, LOL. have a nice evening!

Answer (score 1):

assuming you have the all combinations of full-length solution, then to get all lengths for `{1, 2, 3, 4}`, do the following:

- get all length-4 solutions
- remove `1` to get `{2, 3, 4}` and call this solution recursively
- remove `2` to get `{1, 3, 4}` and call this solution recursively
- remove `3` to get `{1, 2, 4}` and call this solution recursively
- remove `4` to get `{1, 2, 3}` and call this solution recursively

naturally, when you are down to just a single element, don't try to solve it but just return it as the only permutation.

Answer (score 0):

If computation time is not an issue you could simply take those "lot of examples" you have seen for computing all permutations of a given set and then run it through all subsets of your input.